# Codeigniter resize issue after transferring server

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-processing

The code was working like a charm for me. But I have now transferred the files from one server to another, and it is not working now. The image is being uploaded (original) -> `image.jpg` but the other two images after resize `thumb_image.jpg` and `featured_image.jpg` are not being uploaded. I dont know what the problem is.

I went through the error log and I see these 3 lines of codes

```
ERROR - 2013-09-08 17:38:26 --> PNG images are not supported.
ERROR - 2013-09-08 17:38:26 --> The path to the image is not correct.
ERROR - 2013-09-08 17:38:26 --> Your server does not support the GD function required to process this type of image.
```

I dont understand whats the issue with the image path and why does it says PNG images are not supported as it was working perfectly fine.

The resize code is

```
public function resizeIMG($imagePath, $filename){

        $this->load->library('image_lib');

        $configThumb['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $configThumb['source_image']    = $imagePath; 
        $configThumb['create_thumb'] = FALSE;
        $configThumb['new_image'] = 'thumb_'.$filename;
        $configThumb['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
        $configThumb['width']    = 260;
        $configThumb['height']  = 215;


        $configFeatured['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $configFeatured['source_image'] = $imagePath; 
        $configFeatured['create_thumb'] = FALSE;
        $configFeatured['new_image'] = 'featured_'.$filename;
        $configFeatured['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
        $configFeatured['width']     = 800;
        $configFeatured['height']   = 500;


        $configCropFeatured['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $configCropFeatured['source_image'] = './uploads/featured_'.$filename;
        $configCropFeatured['x_axis'] = '0';
        $configCropFeatured['y_axis'] = '0'; 
        $configCropFeatured['create_thumb'] = FALSE;
        $configCropFeatured['new_image'] = 'featured_'.$filename;
        $configCropFeatured['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
        $configCropFeatured['width']     = 720;
        $configCropFeatured['height']   = 250;

        $this->image_lib->initialize($configThumb);
        $this->image_lib->resize();
        $this->image_lib->initialize($configFeatured);
        $this->image_lib->resize();

        $this->image_lib->initialize($configCropFeatured);
        $this->image_lib->crop();


    }
```

Comment: you are probably using wrong image_library, just test other ones (GD, GD2, ImageMagick, NetPBM). (not wrong but not installed on your server) to see what libraries are installed use `phpinfo()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logs say `Your server does not support the GD function required to process this type of image.` which means that your server host has not enabled the GD library (or possibly banned the functions you are using for whatever reason)

You will need to contact your webhost to see if they can enable GD. If not, you will need to convert your application to use a different library. You can find out which libraries are available by running `phpinfo()` inside a PHP script. If GD is disabled, it's most likely that instead, [ImageMagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) is turned on - you can check out that page and you will be able to convert your application to use ImageMagick once you understand the basic functions. Please make sure that ImageMagick (or `imagick`) is **somewhere in phpinfo()**. If not, you're probably best asking your host to enable either of the plugins.

Comment: Yea already did it, and yes the server was a new setup so the function was not enabled.